# How to use message queue over internet

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, amazon-sqs

So basically we have a backend hosted in the cloud. This backend is composed of Web Servers (Django/Python), Databases (Postgresql), RabbitMQ, and Workers (Celery)

We also have hardware components around the world. Those hardware components need to get things done from the backend. We were thinking of using RabbitMQ to store their jobs and using a polling mechanism from hardware components to get jobs to do.

We saw that with Amazon SQS we can achieve this. They have a system allowing to get jobs in HTTPS with long-polling, which is really perfect. I was wondering if such a solution exist for RabbitMQ or other messaging system we could host our-self? I read that rabbitMQ was not designed to be exposed on the internet and I was not able to find any relevant answer to my problem.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you need to use the HTTP protocol? or can you  use other protocols?

Comment: It would be better using HTTP protocol but I'm open using other protocal from the moment I can access it from a python client or something else.

Comment: have you seen this? https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html this is perfect for wan configuration, but it requires an Rabbitmq for each "remote" server.

Comment: Check out also this https://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html