# RabbitMQ/Android - how to setup a connection?

Tags: java, android, rabbitmq

I'm trying to make an Android application which would consist of communication (simply passing a fixed message) between devices using message brokers (I chose RabbitMQ). For a couple of days I've been struggling with setting up the connection. The client side is not ready yet, I'd like to make my server work firstly.

Here is a piece of my code:

```
public class HomeView extends Fragment {
ImageButton imageButton;
private String mText;
private View mContent;

public HomeView() { }

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mContent = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_view, container, false);
    configureImageButton();
    setupServer();
    return mContent;
}

private void configureImageButton() {
    imageButton = (ImageButton) getmContent().findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    ImageButton.OnClickListener listener = new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // message to server will be sent here
        }
    };
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
}

Thread setupServerThread;

ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
void setupServer() {
    setupServerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                try {
                    Connection connection = null;
                    factory.setUri("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/");
                    connection = factory.newConnection();
                    final Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
                    channel.queueDeclare(RPC_QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);
                    channel.basicQos(1);

                    Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
                        @Override
                        public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws IOException {
                            AMQP.BasicProperties replyProps = new AMQP.BasicProperties
                                    .Builder()
                                    .correlationId(properties.getCorrelationId())
                                    .build();

                            String response = "";

                            try {
                                String message = new String(body,"UTF-8");
                                int n = Integer.parseInt(message);
                                response += n.toString());
                            }
                            catch (RuntimeException e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            finally {
                                channel.basicPublish( "", properties.getReplyTo(), replyProps, response.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                                channel.basicAck(envelope.getDeliveryTag(), false);
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    channel.basicConsume(RPC_QUEUE_NAME, false, consumer);

                    while(true) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException _ignore) {}
                    }
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    setupServerThread.start();
}
}
```

The problem is that after this line:

```
connection = factory.newConnection();
```

the connection is null and the "Connection refused" Exception is thrown. 
When I ran the same code as a simple Java program, everything worked fine.

Please take a look, I would very very much appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: while(true)? really?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631904/how-to-use-message-queue-over-internet